# Reduce an array of objects & tally the values of their array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
const data = [
  {a: 'happy', b: 'robin', c: ['blue','green']}, 
  {a: 'tired', b: 'panther', c: ['green','black','orange','blue']}, 
  {a: 'sad', b: 'goldfish', c: ['green','red']}
];
```

How would I loop through the main data array and tally how many times a color value is present?

Do I start with a `.map` first and then reduce within the map function?

The outcome I'm looking for is:

```
{blue: 2, green: 3, black: 1, orange: 1, red: 1}
```

Comment: _"Do I start with a .map first and then reduce within the map function?"_ - Sounds good. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it at one-go using `Array.prototype.reduce`: in each iteration of `data`, you simply iterate through all the colors in the array, check them individually against the accumulator if they exist:

- If exists, then increment count by 1
- Otherwise, set starting value to 1

```js
const data = [
  {a: 'happy', b: 'robin', c: ['blue','green']}, 
  {a: 'tired', b: 'panther', c: ['green','black','orange','blue']}, 
  {a: 'sad', b: 'goldfish', c: ['green','red']}
];

const count = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const colors = cur.c;
  
  colors.forEach(color => {
    acc[color] = acc[color] ? acc[color] + 1 : 1;
  });
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```